# Distinguish between validation errors in Laravel

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using the validation rules in Laravel 4, which are very powerful. However, I wonder how one can distinguish between the different validations error that may occur. For example if I use the following rules:

```
$rules = array(
  'email'  => 'required|email|confirmed',
  'email_confirmation' => 'required|email',
);
```

How can I tell what validation rule/rules that triggered the error for a certain field? Is there some way I can tell that the error was due to a missing email value, email wasn't a valid email address and/or the email couldn't be confirmed?

I quite new to laravel as I began working with it a week ago so I hope someone may shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation messages returned by the validation instance should hold the key to knowing what went wrong.

You can access the messages given by the validator object by using:

```
$messages = $validator->messages(); // Where $validator is your validator instance.
$messages = $messages->all()
```

That should give you an instance of a `MessageBag` object, that you can run through with a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($messages as $message) {
    print $message;
}
```

And inside there, you should find your answer, i.e. there will be a message saying something like: "Email confirmation must match the 'email' field".

Comment: Just as an addition to this: i don't think there is a way to tell using the returned response which 'rule' failed, i.e. are you looking for something that says `'required' => false, 'confirmed' => true`, as i don't think that exists.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response Daniel. I will try to live with the default validation messages then and adjust the field names using the attributes array in validation.php in languages dir.

Answer (score 2):

You can get error messages for a given attribute:

`$errors = $validation->errors->get('email');`

and then loop through the errors

`foreach ($errors as $error) {
    print $error;
}`

or get all the error messages

`$errors = $validation->errors->all();`

then loop through the error messages

`foreach ($errors as $error) {
    print $error;
}`

You can see more information about laravel validation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/validation)